# Is there a GDB backend for ARM Debug Architecture?

Tags: debugging, gdb, arm, jtag

ARMv7-A&R architecture manual (DDI0-406B) section C1 defines a debug interface through a series of memory mapped (or CP14 mapped) registers. Features include hardware breakpoints, hardware watchpoints, vector catch, and execution of ARM instructions in debug state. It seems like the perfect alternative to JTAG debugging which usually involves expensive cable and software.

From playing around with my Cortex A9 MPcore device, I found that it is possible for one core to enter debug state and have another core control it (step debugging, breakpoint set, etc). I was wondering if anyone has gone beyond that and implemented the GDB remote serial protocol with this interface?

Comment: I guess that a Linux kernel deal with these.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain? Are you saying there's a Linux module that interfaces with ADI? If that's the case, it would be an interesting code base to look at. But I'm doing bare metal development. The closest thing I could find was OpenOCD but that runs on a host (I could implement a transfer protocol though)

Comment: I've done it a couple times at different companies; I don't know if there's anything open-source or not.